# Using #define in a #ifdef

Tags: c++

Is it possible to define a define variable in an #ifdef statement?

```
#ifdef VALUE
#define VARIABLE 1
#else
#define VARIABLE 1
#endif
```

Comment: Yes it's possible. Exactly as you did.

Comment: Certainly yes.  It's done all the time.

Comment: You can easily try this yourself in 30 seconds and see what happens. Which is why you are getting all the downvotes.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, just a directive per line:

```
#ifdef VALUE
  #define VARIABLE 1
#else
  #define VARIABLE 1
#endif
```

Comment: Ok, you edited, so it is just as you say.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but not like that:

```
#ifdef VALUE
 int VARIABLE = 1;
#else
 int VARIABLE = 2;
#endif
```

These are variable definitions. What you're doing is defining some preprocessor directives. You couldn't do `VARIABLE = 3` in your case, but you can here.

Comment: +1 for a good answer to a terrible question.

Comment: Might change the casing if it isn't constant, though.